# store object inside object with function

Tags: javascript

```
var displayImage = "displayImage";
var obj = ['object'];
var json = {};

storemap(displayImage, obj);

function storemap(j, setobject){
    json.idnumber = j;
    json.objetstyle = setobject;
    return;
}

console.log(json);
in return
    Object {idnumber: "displayImage", objetstyle: Array[1]}idnumber: "displayImage"objetstyle: Array[1]__proto__: Object
```

i wanted to save my canvas json to my object , but i dont know how to create the map i wanted .i want the object map to be like this. so basic is object within object.

i want store displayImage to json and then store the obj to displayImage.

i just wanted to know how to store object inside object so it will be

```
json -> displayImage -> obj

json =[
    displayImage1:[
           objetstyle: ["objects"];    
    ]
]
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/bsbjcww8/)

Comment: `[]` denotes an array. `{}` would denote an object (You also have an extra `]` at the end!). Your desired result is confusing.

Comment: What is `object`? If you meant `new Object`, then you should consider using a simple literal (`{}`) instead.

Comment: Please show us your `Canvas` object (and its `.toJSON` method if you've written that yourself).

Comment: sorry i try edit the question .

Comment: you dont need to store your object you can just take a ref to this object like  `var obj = document.getElementById('canvas')' and then you will get a reference to this object

Comment: @Jung could you show us how your canvas object looks like? or this is a html element?

Comment: the canvas object is too long , the obj will relplace it i just need know how to put the obj inside my displayImage. thank guys.